# Fusion of two MNIST classification modules

Tags: python, machine-learning, mnist

I have trained two MNIST classification(final_model_0_4 and final_model_5_9) models on digit 0-4 and 5-9 respectively and both the models are giving me the expected results when I am testing them with test data. How can I merge these two models such that my new model is able to classify digits from 0-9 without any further training ? Definition of my classification models is as under:-

```
`def define_model():
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
# compile model
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model`
```

I have tried simply combining these two models by the following code:-

```
`import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Load model 1 and model 2
model1 = keras.models.load_model('final_model_0_4.h5') 
model2 = keras.models.load_model('final_model_5_9.h5')  

# Remove the last layer from model1 and model2
model1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model1.layers[-1].output)  
model2 = keras.models.Model(inputs=model2.input, outputs=model2.layers[-1].output)    
# Create a new combined model
combined_model = keras.models.Sequential()
# Add the common architecture layers of model1
combined_model.add(model1)
# Add the common architecture layers of model2
combined_model.add(model2)
# Add a new output layer for digits 0-9
combined_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
# Compile the combined model
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9)
combined_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss= 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Save the combined model
combined_model.save('combined_model.h5')`
```

However I am getting the following error:-

```
`ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_3" (type Functional).`
```

Comment: There is literally no theoretical or practical way in ML to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears unconventional to identify the digit 0 through 9 using these two pre-trained classifiers. For instance, supplying the digit 7 to the model `final_model_0_4` or the digit 3 to `final_model_5_9` would pose issues.

If you intend to classify digits from 0 to 9 **without any further training**, you should not replace your pre-trained models like this:

```py
# Remove the last layer from model1 and model2
model1 = keras.models.Model(inputs=model1.input, outputs=model1.layers[-1].output)  
model2 = keras.models.Model(inputs=model2.input, outputs=model2.layers[-1].output) 

# Add a densely-connected output layer
combined_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

This newly added densely-connected neural network layer `keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')` is untrained.

However, if you wish to use `final_model_0_4` and `final_model_5_9` for digit classification from 0 to 9 without further training, I recommend the following approach.

For example, when you feed the digit 3 into `final_model_0_4`, you'll receive five values in the output, representing the probabilities of the digit 3 belonging to the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. Similarly, by inputting the digit 3 into `final_model_5_9`, you'll obtain five values, indicating the probabilities of the digit 3 being classified as 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. Finally, you can compare these ten probability values and select the highest one for classification.

Comment: @Chih_Hao Liu, the technique you mentioned worked